# Out of memory error in loading multiple models in Forge Viewer

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

I am working on a project that has 14 Navisworks (NWC) models. I am able to load the composite model into the viewer (which takes some time but works).

However, when I am loading models one by one into Viewer, I get out of memory error before all 14 are loaded. Total file size is about 500MB.

I observed that viewer is very responsive right until browser crashes (while model loading was taking place in the background).

I suspect this to be an issue of total number of polygons & geometry. I tied to use NOP_VIEWER.initDebugTools() extension but it doesn't seem to show total count from all models. It seems to show the details of only first model.

1. Is there a way to stop Viewer creating more geometry before it runs out of memory?
2. Is there a way to find statistics of all models with DebugTools extension?
3. Is there another way to count polygons of loaded models?

Thanks
Bandu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to stop Viewer creating more geometry before it runs out of memory?

Try and limit the memory consumption in your load options:

```
var config3d = {
    memory: {
        limit: 1024 // in MB
    }
};
var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D(container, config3d);
```

BTW the default limits are:

```
Desktop 600 MB
Mobile  195 MB
```

> Is there a way to find statistics of all models with DebugTools extension?

Unfortunately the built-in `DebugTools` does not work with multiple models.

But that shouldn't stop you from querying stats on a per model basis:

```
let modelArray = viewer.impl.modelQueue().getModels();
let targetModel = modelArray[index];
targetModel.getGeometryList() // retrieves geometry info about a specific model
```

You can even bake an extension of your own to suit multiple models.

> Is there another way to count polygons of loaded models?

```
model.getGeometryList().geomPolyCount
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will build some settings/tools with these

Comment: I have included these into my product code. One question: memory limit is the amount to be 'reserved'? Or to be used? I assume that is the former. Thanks.

Comment: Don't think there's really a way to `reserve` memory on modern browsers yet so the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that is right way or not but I noticed, NOP_VIEWERS objects are not releasing because of that may be you get out of memory. so when you switching or changing your model while loading into viewer call below function. that will remove existing viewers objects from memory and release your memory.

```
function clearModels() {
 //remove currently loaded object
 delete(NOP_VIEWER); 
 //remove previously loaded model objects
 NOP_VIEWERS.forEach(nviewer => { nviewer.finish(); delete(nviewer); }); 
}
```

Comment: if you can not get NOP_VIEWER or NOP_VIEWERS object use window["NOP_VIEWERS"]

Comment: Check heap memory allocation with "window.performance.memory"