# Forge viewer crashes after loading some large models

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, autodesk-forge, autodesk

I have been trying to load the model over 200MB on the ios app, but the viewer crashes after loading a few seconds. In the web inspecter, it returns many 404 errors. This error only happens on the ios app and not happens on the android app.

[image: Error Image]

In my mind, I think it is related to the memory limit. I check the document of viewer v7 [Allocate Memory for Large Models](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/memory-limit/) and [Update memory limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55590793/out-of-memory-error-in-loading-multiple-models-in-forge-viewer) but with no fortunate. How could I load the large model on ios app with forge viewer?

Comment: What kind of browser are you using for the loading of the model? based on the console screenshot looks like chrome, but want to make sure. What kind of model it is? Navis, Revit? That might help us give you a pointer to what to look for.

Comment: I inspected the model on safari. The Revit model. After testing, I think the problem could happen in two aspects. One may be related to the forge viewer memory limit and another could be the ionic webview plugin. The app could possibly run out of Memory/CPU and cause the reload. I am not sure what is the main problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok based on my colleague's experience, Ionic suffers from web performance problems on mobile, such as 'animation jank', Navigation bugs, keyboard popup bugs with Form input and memory bloat, which could be the main reason why the Viewer is running out of memory.

I will suggest maybe trying React Native. These apps are written in javascript, where the JSC/V8 engine creates & manipulates Native UI components for both iPhone and Android platforms.  This gives your app speed and the buttery smooth animation, of a typical native app written in Xcode/Swift and Android Studio/Java. Hence, React Native app's don't suffer the problems that Cordova/Ionic do.

Here is a blog post to help you develop the app. 
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-react-native-au-talk